# Telegram Bot won't leave private chat

Tags: telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I created quite nice bot for telegram but facing now some issues with security. I want my bot to work only in certain group which i allow ( already done by group_id) but i want also to block option to write to my bot in private message. I could block adding to groups from BotFather options but still people can write to him in private messages.

I tried to use function when someone write to him:

```
bot.leave_chat(message.chat.id)
```

But bot still don't want to leave private conversation with people. How could I prevent in this or other way from adding my bot or trying to flood him with requests?

Answer (score 2):

Technically [it's not possible](https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq#what-messages-will-my-bot-get) to forbid people to write messages directly to a Bot:

> 1. All bots, regardless of settings, will receive:
>
> - All service messages.
> - All messages from private chats with users.
> - All messages from channels where they are a member.

As per your question, I'd suggest to create a simple stub reply for private chats something like `This Bot doesn't answer in private`.

Leaving a chat might not "explain" people anything. I guess it rather will push them to try again and again, because it's not clear "Why bot disappears with no reason" ;)

Comment: Thanks for response! I was hoping it was possible. Anyway i am looking for some protection against flooding the bot with commands even if they dont work for other people than me.